# Erlang - Skip test suite immediately in common test

Tags: erlang, common-test

I know the way to skip test suite is:

***Let init_per_suite function return {skip, reason} value***. But It will execute all commands in the init_per_suite function before skip.

I want to skip test suite immediately when a condition is met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe just test the condition early in `init_per_suite` and abort:

```
init_per_suite(Config) ->
    case abort_condition_met() of
        true ->
            {skip,abort_condition_met};
        false ->
            %% run functions
            Config
    end.
```

Or you can omit the testsuite from the command to start `common_test`. For example, if you run `common_test` using `ct_run`, create a config which suites your requirements.